# Скрытие элементов

Tags: javascript

Я полный нуб в JS.

```
<ul> Programming languages
    <li onclick="disappear()"> C++</li>
    <li onclick="disappear()"> C#</li>
    <li onclick="disappear()"> Pascal</li>
    <li onclick="disappear()"> Java</li>
    <li onclick="disappear()"> PHP</li>
    <li onclick="disappear()"> Basic</li>
    <li onclick="disappear()"> Fortran</li>
</ul>
```

Нужно, чтоб при нажатии `li` удалялся. Что в теле `disapper` записать?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, не надо писать такого ужаса ^.^

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
    <li class="deletable">C++</li>
    <li class="deletable">C#</li>
    <li class="deletable">Pascal</li>
    <li class="deletable">Java</li>
    <li class="deletable">PHP</li>
    <li class="deletable">и т.д.</li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function removeElement() {
    // собственно удаление элемента...
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}
function initDeletableNav() {
    // сначала выберем все элементы в массив 
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("deletable");
    var elementsLength = elements.length;

    // теперь пройдемся циклом по массиву...
    for( var i=0; i<elementsLength; i++ ) {
        elements[i].addEventListener( "click", removeElement, false );
        // запишем обработчик для каждого элемента
    }
}

window.addEventListener( "load", initDeletableNav, false );
//  инициализируем обработку событий на загрузку окна
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function disappear(el) { el.style.display = 'none'; }

<li onclick="disappear(this)"> C++ </li>
```

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: А я удалил, т.к. не учел так же изначально, что обращение к элементу идет через функцию `disappear()`.